# Ignoring types with fluent configuration in Typelite

Tags: typelite

I'm providing a list of types I want to generate, these types depend on many others which also get generated.
I don't need many of these referenced types. Is it possible to configure Typelite (with fluent configuration) to not generate specific properties and with that prevent their types from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible (at least right now) to configure TypeLite to ignore a property with the fluent configuration. You can use he `[TsIgnore]` attribute on properties, you want to ignore.